# Factory Girl - How to create a factory for a model that has associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I am attempting to create a factory for my user model, along with its associations. However, I cannot seem to get the syntax right in my Factory Girl code. I've read through the Factory Girl documentation but cannot seem to find any help with my specific use case. The errors I am currently receiving when I run my test suite are:

```
undefined method `subscription_args' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner...
```

and

```
Trait not registered: valid_card_data
```

Here are my models and associations:

**User.rb**

```
has_one :subscription
has_one :plan, :through => :subscription
has_many :projects
```

**Project.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Plan.rb**

```
has_many :subscriptions
```

**Subscription.rb**

```
belongs_to :plan
belongs_to :user
```

and

And here is my Factory Girl code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    first_name "Joel"
    last_name "Brewer"
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.com".downcase }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
    user_type "entrepreneur"

    subscription { build(:subscription, subscription_args) }

    after(:create) do |user|
      user.subscription.save!
    end
  end

  factory :subscription do
    user
    plan_id '4'

    ## I am trying to access a helper method from support/utilities ##
    ## This call to valid_card_data doesn't seem to be working...   ##

    stripe_card_token valid_card_data 
    email "joel.brewer@example.com"
  end

  factory :project do
    title "Sample Project"
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md under associations.

Comment: I've tried reading through the documentation, I can't seem to get it to work for my use case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've done it in the past.  Certainly not the only way:

(Note I am using cucumber.)

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do |f|
    f.username 'superman'
  end

  factory :message do |f|
    f.association :user
    f.content 'Test message content'
  end

end
```

This establishes that the message factory should associate the message to a user.  Which user?  I establish that at the point of use:

steps.rb:

```
Given(/^there is a user$/) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

Given(/^the user has posted the message "(.*?)"$/) do |message_text|
  FactoryGirl.create(:message, :content => message_text, :user => @user)
end

When(/^I visit the page for the user$/) do
  visit user_path(@user)
end

Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |text|
  page.should have_content(text)
end
```

My approach, specifying at the point of use makes sense for *this* use case.  e.g. Given is a user (user must be established first) and that user has posted a message (now the relationship between the existing user and the message can be established)...

That may or may not work out well for you, but it's how I've done it.  This may or may not have helped you, but here's hoping.

Comment: Kent, you are awesome. I've been blowing my brains out trying to figure this out the past two days. Much appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. Here is one example:

```
after(:build) do |keyword, evaluator|
  keyword.text = FactoryGirl.build(:keyword_text, :value => evaluator.keyword_text)
end
```

You dont need `subscription_args` - these can be set when you call the factory.

Where are you defining your trait?

In my factories they look like this:

```
trait :with_category_associations do
  ..
```

For more complicated relationships you probably want to use:

```
  after(:create) do |keyword, evaluator|
    evaluator.categories.each do |category|
      FactoryGirl.create(:join_inventory_keyword, final: keyword, category: category)
    end
  end
```